# Qt TableView only sorting once

Tags: sql, qt, tableview

I have a QTableView that is populated with a QSqlQueryModel. I am trying to sort the table based on which RadioButton is checked, but nothing is happening when I press them. There was one point where I could get it to sort, but only once. What am I doing wrong here?

```
void MainWindow::on_openButton_clicked()
{
    QString filePath = ui->lineEdit->text();

    if( filePath != "" ){
        if( openDB( filePath ) ){
            ui->debugLabel->setText("Database opened");
            MainWindow::populateTable();
        }else{
            ui->debugLabel->setText("Unable to open database");
        }
    } else {
        ui->debugLabel->setText("Path is empty");
    }
}

void MainWindow::populateTable(){
    if( readDB() ){
        ui->tableView->setModel(toast.dbModel);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_shootButton_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if( checked ){
        ui->tableView->sortByColumn( 0 );
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_winButton_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if( checked ){
        ui->tableView->sortByColumn( 1 );
    }

}
bool openDB(QString path){
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(path);
    return db.open();
}
bool readDB(){
    if( db.isOpen() ){
        dbModel->setQuery( "select * from test", db );
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`QSqlQueryModel` isn't sortable by default, `QSqlTableModel` *is* sortable but there's differences between the two. You can make `QSqlQueryModel` sortable by  inheriting the class and reimplementing the `sort()` method though, if you have a look at the documentation for `QAbstractItemModel` it'll give you some details about it.